# Use of class=“dropdown-toggle” in dropdown

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Below is my code for showing a dropdown. In my code, if I remove class "dropdown-toggle" then also it works fine. So I am wandering what is the use of "dropdown-toggle" class?

```
<div class="container">
<div class="dropdown">
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" class="btn dropdown-toggle">Options<span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="#">About Me</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">About Appirio Inc</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for more about dropdown-doggle : http://www.tutorialspoint.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_dropdown_plugin.htm

Comment: But this still doesn't answer my question. Why class is being used?